# error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/track' with config ''

Tags: android

Duplicate value for resource  `attr/track` with `config` migrated the project from `Eclipse IDE` to `Android Studio(Version 3.0.1)` now getting these issues.

Comment: Just rename whatever attribute you've named tint to something like libtrack or lib_track  or even more obscure ili_lib_track so the issue can be resolved. after that clean, rebuild project.

Comment: thanks @Hemant Parmar

Answer (score 1):

This attribute interferes with your project and one library.
change track to other unic name for example track_2 and clean project